# Invert mocha's diff colors output?

Tags: mocha.js

For example, by default, background colors is green or red. I'd like to have green/red as a foreground, and background to be my default color (which is white).

Because it's really hard to see anything on light terminal color scheme, since foreground is black and background changes to red or green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mocha source there is a file called base.js under the reporters directory. There you can alter the colors according to the bash color guide. http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: wrong, you can change it in that base.js but it has absolutely no effect...the colors do not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `project.json` entry for test to `mocha -C` to disable all coloring in the terminal output, for better readability.